# React Redux dispatch payload reaches case with data but doesnt save it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Having trouble with the updating of state in my reducer.

I have the following reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  isAuthorised: false,
  username: null,
  jwt: null,
  SuburbPostcodeDropDownList: null,
  StateDropDownList: null,
  CompanyStateShortName: null,
  error: null,
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        isAuthorised: false,
        username: action.payload,
        jwt: null,
        error: null,
      }
    case RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isAuthorised: true,
        jwt: action.payload,
        error: null,
      }
    case ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isAuthorised: false,
        username: null,
        jwt: null,
        error: action.payload,
      }

    case REQUEST_SELECT_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        isAuthorised: false,
        jwt: action.payload,
        SuburbPostcodeDropDownList: null,
        StateDropDownList: null,
        CompanyStateShortName: null,
        error: null,
      }

    case RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isAuthorised: true,
        SuburbPostcodeDropDownList: action.payload.SuburbPostcodeDropDownList,
        StateDropDownList: action.payload.StateDropDownList,
        CompanyStateShortName: action.payload.CompanyStateShortName
      }
```

It gets to RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN with the payload. Two of the items are arrays. Here is a picture of it reaching the correct case option with its data.

[image]

When it completes and I look at the redux extension in chrome it hasnt updated the state.

[image]

I cant work out why it hasnt updated the sate? I have set the name of the returned data to the state names etc but its not changing from initial state or even registering they exist in the login part of the tree.

Wondering what I have done wrong?

**EDIT**

As requested here is the code that does the dispatch:

```
export const requestLoginToken = (username, password) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: REQUEST_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: username })

    const payload = {
      userName: username,
      password: password,
    }

    const task = fetch('/api/jwt', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
      },
    })
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: data })
        saveJwt(data)

        //selectData()
        dispatch({ type: REQUEST_SELECT_DATA })

        const token = getJwt()
        const headers = new Headers({
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        })
        const retrieveSelectData = fetch('/api/SelectData/SelectData', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers,
        })
          .then(handleErrors)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(selectData => {
            dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_SELECT_DATA, payload: selectData })

          })

      })
      .catch(error => {
        clearJwt()
        dispatch({ type: ERROR_LOGIN_TOKEN, payload: error.message })
      })
    addTask(task)
    return task
  }
```

It fetches the data via retrieveSelectData...

Comment: debugging shows you are on `REQUEST_SELECT_DATA` case. Paste some code showing how you actually dispatching actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing the payload in the reducer you're capitalizing the first letter when it should be lower case, so

```
SuburbPostcodeDropDownList: action.payload.suburbPostcodeDropDownList
```

instead of:

```
SuburbPostcodeDropDownList: action.payload.SuburbPostcodeDropDownList
```